# `talltblr`, `longtblr`: how to use `\verb` command in caption, note and remarks?

Tags: verbatim, tabularray

Finally MiKTeX provide version 2022A! So, I make some tests if in this new version (2022A) can be used `\verb` command  in caption, note and remark. Unfortunately, as at old version, not (as least as I try):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\footnotesize, 
                         verbr}  % <--- doesn't help ...

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
%caption = {Caption of table where verb doesn't \verb+works+.},
  label = {tab: test},
note{1} = {A footnote with verbatim doesn't \verb+work+.},
                ]{colspec={ll},
                  verb} % work in table body
    \toprule
column 1    & column 2  \\
    \midrule
row1        & value 11\TblrNote{1} . Here verbatim \verb+works+   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives (expected) error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21     \end
             {talltblr}
? x
```

Forcing compilation gives the following result:

[image]

So I wonder, is there a way to use `verb` as as aforementioned? For example as this problem is solved by use of the `cprotect` package in caption outsize `talltblr` or `longtblr` environments or use verb in their table bodies?

Comment: just don't use verb in the argument of another command, it's sometimes possible for individual commands to make some approximation work but that way lies madness. use `\texttt{word}`

Comment: @Zarko I will try to add outer specification `verb` to the package later. Then you will be able to use `\verb` command in the header and footer of the table.

Answer (score 1):

According to the tabularray [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) v2023A, the `verb` option is deprecated and the recommended way to include verbatim content is with the `\fakeverb` command of the [codehigh](https://ctan.org/pkg/codehigh) package. The `\` (excluding commands), `{`, `}`, `#`, `^`,   (space), and `%` characters must be escaped with a backslash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{codehigh}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
%caption = {Caption of table where verb doesn't \verb+works+.},
  label = {tab: test},
note{1} = {A footnote with (fake) verbatim does \fakeverb{work\%$^_&\cmd}.},
                ]{colspec={ll},
                  verb} % work in table body
    \toprule
column 1    & column 2  \\
    \midrule
row1        & value 11\TblrNote{1} . Here verbatim \verb+works+   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Thank you  very much for answer (+1). I need a some time to read  `codehigh` package documentation, and mentioned section in the `tabularray` package.